# WCF self hosting is not working

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace helloserviceDemo2
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IHelloService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string sayHello(string name);
    }

    class HelloService : IHelloService
    {
        public string sayHello(string name)
        {
            return name + " welcome";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService));
             BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
             host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloService), httpBinding, "http://localhost:8080/helloservice");

             host.Open();
             Console.WriteLine("service is running now");
             Console.ReadKey();
         }
    }
}
```

When I am running this application, it runs well. But this url is not getting with service. Please help me come out of this problem. Thanks

Comment: "url is not getting with service" can you elaborate, do you get a error message, a time out, or something else entirely? Also can you please include the details of how you are accessing the service.

Comment: Not getting what? Not getting along?

Comment: Perhaps try adding a base address to there ServiceHost Constructor like such : 
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService), new Uri("http://localhost:8080"))

Comment: By chance you are not running an OS with IIS running and capturing the port are you?

Answer (score 0):

Try with base URI :

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService), new Uri("http://localhost:8080"));
            BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloService), httpBinding, "http://localhost:8080/helloservice");

            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("service is running now");
            Console.ReadKey();
```